# JDK doesn't see application and other classes

Tags: java, javafx

The imports are there, but compiler says Application, FXMLLoader don't exist. I have configured for JRE and JDK 11, using Eclipse with JavaFX extension.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Apps.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: From Java 9 onwards, you need to explicitly list the modules you need (`javafx.graphics`).

Comment: Furthermore afaik javafx has been removed from the jdk in java 11. It should be available via some external project...

Answer (score 2):

As Fabian already said in his comment, starting with JDK11 JavaFX is not included in the JDK anymore. You can download a separate SDK for JavaFX here: http://jdk.java.net/openjfx/